# Input field not registering javascript event on first click/focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a datepicker() object on input textboxes. So all inputs with the .dateField class would trigger a datepicker() on click/focus. But it isnt working. 
It does not work the first time i click. If i click outside the box and then again click inside the box, it works.

```
$(".dateField").bind('click focus change', function(){
            $(this).datepicker();
        })
```

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: `$(".dateField").datepicker();` should be enough...

Comment: Perhaps the box is *already* focused when the page loads, but before you bind the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datepicker` function equips your input with all the needed callbacks and code.

It is not meant to be called as a reaction to "click" or "focus".

It should be called only once, at initialization :

```
$(function(){
    $(".dateField").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [date picker from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), you will need to call the `datepicker` method before the first interaction with the element e.g. on DOM ready:

```
$(function () {
    $(".dateField").datepicker();
});
```

The way you are currently doing it will initialize the date picker on first interaction (in fact, it will initialize it on *every* interaction), but it won't show it on the first.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/jUCqc/) containing both versions. Uncomment your version of the code (and comment out my version) to see the difference.